# Able to delete a file without permissions

Tags: java, tomcat, permissions, delete-file, windows-server-2012-r2

**Why am I able to delete a file in my Java code despite the Tomcat user not having the deletion permissions?**

My server is running the following code, which deletes and recreates a file if it exists:

```
File fileCSV = new File(filePath);
    try {
        if (fileCSV.exists()) {
            fileCSV.delete();
        }
        fileCSV.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new FooImportException("Error creating new file");
    }
```

It is able to delete the file despite the user used by the server not having deletion permissions - only read and write permissions.

[image]

I am certain that these are the relevant permissions, as the code fails on the file creation line without the "Create files / Write data" permissions.  However, **it does not fail** on the deletion line when lacking the "Delete" permission.  **What might be the reasoning for this?**

Comment: You need to go read the JavaDocs and see what it says about `File#delete`.  `delete` does not throw an exception, it returns a `boolean` stated the success of the operation

Comment: @MadProgrammer Interesting!  I wouldn't have even considered that.  That sounds worthy of a full-fledged answer.

Comment: I’m pretty sure it’s been asked and answered before

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay, well, feel free to mark it as a duplicate instead if you want to.  I certainly did my due research beforehand and didn't find such a question, though clearly I didn't know the correct thing to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JavaDocs for `File#delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete--)

> `public boolean delete()`
>  Deletes the file or directory denoted by
>   this abstract pathname. If this pathname denotes a directory, then the
>   directory must be empty in order to be deleted. 
> Note that the `Files`
>   class defines the `delete` method to throw an `IOException` when a file
>   cannot be deleted. This is useful for error reporting and to diagnose
>   why a file cannot be deleted.
>
> Returns:
>  `true` if and only if the file or directory is successfully
>   deleted; `false` otherwise
>  Throws:
>  `SecurityException` - If a
>   security manager exists and its
>   `SecurityManager.checkDelete(java.lang.String)` method denies delete
>   access to the file

So, `File#delete` does not actually throw an `Exception` when the file can't be deleted, but instead returns a `boolean` based on the success of the operation.

If the `Exception` is important to you, then you should use [`Files#delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-) instead.

It's important to note - this only solves the question of "why does it not fail" based on the available code, not the question of "would it fail" based on the available file permissions